# Hibernate validator error - 4.0.2.GA

Tags: hibernate, validation

the validate function of the Hibernate Validator seems to be buggy (version hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar). Do I maybe miss a dependency?

Part of my stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Persistence.getPersistenceUtil()Ljavax/persistence/PersistenceUtil;
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:764)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:331)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:260)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:213)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
```

Comment: Can't do anything without the hibernate configuration...  perhaps you have a property specified in the configuration that does not exist in the class.  Please provide more information, and also read up on how to ask questions on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's due to the fact that it thinks you're using JPA2 but in fact you're using JPA1. Remove the jpa-api-2.0.Beta-20090815.jar which is included with the distribution of Hibernate Validator if you don't need it and try again.

Comment: We found a solution to our original problem and stopped searching on that point. So, I still don't know the solution but it must have something to do with the versions. Thank you for the help anyway..

Comment: Awesome, just found this on Google, removing that jar fixed it for me.  You're a legend!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug which have been fixed in version 4.2.0.Beta1 of the Hibernate validator according to this Jira: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HV-374

The stack trace is very confusing because it suggests that Java 5 is being used but I was certain that I was running Java 6.

I also did not have the option to update the validator and I was already running ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar which is a proposed solution by @Gaim so I needed to create my own CustomTraversableResolver which forces JPA1. Details on how to do that are available here: http://soadev.blogspot.se/2010/02/jsr-303-bean-validation-error.html

Answer (score 1):

I stuck on this issue today and made some digging on it. I found out @Javi's answer helpful but it didn't solve my problem. Another tens minutes of googling took me to find out the following:

Hibernate validator in version 4.0.2.GA (and probably also in the others) detects the version JPA **by class `javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil`**, because this class is **NOT** contained in JPA 1 but it is in JPA 2. Unfortunately some libraries implements this class what makes the Hibernate a bit confused. In such case it tries to use JPA 2 also in Java 1.5 environment which throws an exception mentioned in the question.

The solution is simple. Find out the library adding this class and remove it. In my case it was **`ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar`**. This bug was reported long time ago and in version **`ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar`** it is fixed. There so this upgrade solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just now I found that there is a current dependency in java 6. Once i upgraded to java 6 all the errors above disappeared.

http://javaprogrammingtips4u.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ejb3-persistence 1.0.2GA to your class path/ maven pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2.GA</version>       
</dependency>
```

There is a good explanation here: [dependency-hell-or-including-jsr303](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/07/dependency-hell-or-including-jsr303-into-a-hibernated-javaee-app/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to hibernate-validator 4.2 + version. I had the same issue with hibernate-validator 4.1.0 but when I upgraded to v 4.2.0 the issue gone

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```